# Can't add the result with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is my javascript calculation tools where you can show a percentage of a value. Well so if the Value is $100 and Percentage is 10% then it will be $10. After that I just added a new field called Other fees so the final result will be $20 (if other fees values is $10). But can't get the result.

**Javascript Part:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pvalue1').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value +=10000
    document.getElementById('pvalue1').value = value;
}

function decrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('pvalue1').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value -=10000
    document.getElementById('pvalue1').value = value;
}

function incrementValueO()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('otherFees').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value +=10000
    document.getElementById('otherFees').value = value;
}

function decrementValueO()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('otherFees').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value -=10000
    document.getElementById('otherFees').value = value;
}


function toggleIncrement()
{
    var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pvalue2').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value +=0.1
    value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
    document.getElementById('pvalue2').value = value;
     $('#pvalue1').trigger("change");
}

function toggleDecrement()
{
    var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('pvalue2').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value -=0.1
    value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)
    document.getElementById('pvalue2').value = value;
     $('#pvalue1').trigger("change");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('#pvalue1').change(function(){
 var agentfee = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100; 
 var otherFees = parseFloat(document.getElementById('otherFees').value);
 var totalOtherFees = agentfee + otherFees;
 $('#pvalue3').val(totalOtherFees);

 var percentagereduce = parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
 var newvalue = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100; 
 $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);         
 var takevalue1 = parseFloat($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
 var takevalue2 = parseFloat($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
 var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;
 var finalvalue = parseFloat(finalvalue).toFixed(2)
 $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);
});

  $('#pvalue2').change(function(){


 var agentfee = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100; 
 $('#pvalue3').val(agentfee);

 var percentagereduce = parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
 var newvalue = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100; 
 $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);         
 var takevalue1 = parseFloat($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
 var takevalue2 = parseFloat($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
 var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;

 $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);    
});   
});   
</script>
```

**Html Part:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <td>House Sale Price:</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td><input name="pvalue1" class="form-control"  onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Enter Sale Price" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue1?>" id="pvalue1" size="20" required ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="incrementValue()" value="+" /><input type="button" onClick="decrementValue()" value="-" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Rate quoted by agent:</td>
    <td>%</td>
    <td><input name="pvalue2"  class="form-control" onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Percentage" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue2?>" id="pvalue2" size="20"  required ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="toggleIncrement()" value="+" /><input type="button" onClick="toggleDecrement()" value="-" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Other Fees</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td><input name="otherFees" class="form-control"  onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Enter Sale Price" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue1?>" id="otherFees" size="20" required ></td>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="incrementValueO()" value="+" /><input type="button" onClick="decrementValueO()" value="-" /> </td>
</tr>

</table>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 <input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Calculate" style="color:white;font-size:20px;" class="btn btn-primary">

<br><br>
<h2>Results</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Agent Fees:</td>
<td>$</td>
<td><input name="pvalue3"  onkeypress="validate(event)"  class="form-control"  placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue3?>" id="pvalue3" size="10" class="resultfield"  ></td></tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><span id='show-me'  class="form-control" style='display:none'><input name="pvalue4" placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue4?>" id="pvalue4" size="10" class="resultfield"  ></span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Reducing the rate the agent is charging by 0.1% will save you: </td>
<td>$</td>
<td><input name="pvalue5"   onkeypress="validate(event)" class="form-control"  placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue5?>" id="pvalue5" size="10" class="resultfield"  ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "But can't get the result" - can you be more specific to what the problem is? I assume there is some error in your javascript code (If your values are strings like "$10", they are not numbers)? Or is there a problem somewhere else?

Comment: @Chris Right now the calculation is ok so far without "other fees" field. It's a new field I just added. If you enter 100 and 10% then Agent fees result will be 10. Ok But I want to add other field value. so the result will be (Agent Fees + Other Fees)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there's a problem with `otherFees`? I see it used here: `document.getElementById('otherFees').value` - is this where the problem is? What does this return?

Comment: @Chris Yes. I think that's the problem.. it's return Nan

Comment: It will possibly be `NaN` after the `parseFloat` call, but if it's `NaN` before that, then there's an entirely different problem...

Comment: @Chris what is the solution for that ?

Comment: For your DOM having a `NaN` value? I'd focus on how the other values are getting there and what is different about `otherFees`. If it's after the `parseFloat` call, then it's because the DOM value is not a number - it's possibly a string or undefined. You'll need to debug to figure out further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not written the change function for otherFee this can be like as follows and will be included on ready function.

```
 $('#otherFees').change(function(){
 var agentfee = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100; 
 var otherFees = parseFloat(document.getElementById('otherFees').value);
 var totalOtherFees = agentfee + otherFees;
 $('#pvalue3').val(totalOtherFees);

 var percentagereduce = parseFloat($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
 var newvalue = parseFloat($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100; 
 $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);         

 var takevalue1 = parseFloat($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
 var takevalue2 = parseFloat($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
 var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;
 var finalvalue = parseFloat(finalvalue).toFixed(2)
 $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);   
});
```

Comment: the Result is not showing...Can you show me on in jsfiddle ?

Comment: u need to add the data and check if it is working. I have entered value and checked it is working

Comment: or specify your exact requirement. ! it's showing the value 20 for 100, 10, 10.

Comment: in your example the +/- button is not working. Do you know why ?

Comment: now check it is working. there was minor problem that script was not getting called for the increment/decrement.

Comment: ..Great but May be +/- is not working yet.. and the "Reducing the rate the agent is charging by 0.1% will save you:" value must be based on only "House Sale Price" e.g. House sales price $100 then 0.1% = 0.1.

Comment: I have not changed any logic of that. your only question was that the other fee was nt having any impact on final value. and that's working fine. and increment/ decrement is based on your logic only